# Mod Rewrite - Ungreedy modifier needed?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in a .htaccess file..

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)-headquarters-([0-9]+)\.html company.php?lid=$2
```

Now my question is, what happens if the matching result from the first parentheses contains a hyphen? There is a very good chance a lot of them will. Is this where the `ungreedy` modifiers come in!?

Comment: Should a different action be taken if there is another hyphen before `-headquarters`? If not, then what you have should work fine. You are not using the `$1` match group in the rewrite anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about it some more and this is actually a case where you DO want ti to be greedy I would think!?

Comment: What this really boils doing to is the syntax that you want to allow in $1 and therefore pass to `company.php` and what you might want to fall through (and result in a 404 for example or be picked up by another rule).  Sometimes you will want to pass "marginal" URIs to `company.php` where its validation will produce a more meaningful error message to the user.  The greedy issue comes into play with companies such as "top-headquarters" which could result in a URI `top-headquarters-headquarters-8563`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in this case you need to make it ungreedy. e.g. `test-headquarters-headquarters-42.html` will match perfectly fine (with `test-headquarters` being `$1`).

But for completeness I will suggest a few options

You can make it ungreedy by adding a `?` after it. So your rule would become (although, it this case, there would not be any case where it would result in different behaviour):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)?-headquarters-([0-9]+)\.html company.php?lid=$2
```

You could also choose match anything except a hyphen by using

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-headquarters-([0-9]+)\.html company.php?lid=$2
```